# Trying to create an index User booked in EACH hour

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

Im making an application where an user can book a hour of training. I want to give the user the option to see who is booked in the training (hour), i made the index bookings in a training but it shows ALL the users that have done a book. I want the index to show JUST the users that booked in A CERTAIN hour, what i mean is if user booked in training_id: 7. When i go to http://localhost:3000/trainings/7/bookings i want to see ONLY the users booked in that hour

This is my code:

Bookings controller

```
class BookingsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :load_training,  only: [:create]

  def new
    @booking = Booking.new
    @training = Training.find(params[:training_id])
    @booking.training_id
  end

  def create
    @booking = @training.bookings.build(booking_params)
    @booking.user = current_user

    if @booking.save
      flash[:success] = "Book created"
      redirect_to trainings_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end


  def index
    @bookings = Booking.all
  end


  def destroy
    @booking = Booking.find(params[:id])
    @booking.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Book deleted"
    redirect_to trainings_path
  end



private
  def booking_params
    params.require(:booking).permit(:user_id, :training_id)
  end

  def load_training
    @training = Training.find(params[:training_id])
  end

end
```

Booking model:

```
class Booking < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :training
  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :training_id, presence: true



end
```

My routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'static_pages#home'
  get    '/signup',               to: 'users#new'
  get    '/contact',              to: 'static_pages#contact'
  get    '/about',                to: 'static_pages#about'
  get    '/login',                to: 'sessions#new'
  post   '/login',                to: 'sessions#create'
  delete '/logout',               to: 'sessions#destroy'
  get    '/book',                 to: 'bookings#new'
  post   '/book',                 to: 'bookings#create'
  delete '/unbook',               to: 'bookings#destroy'


  resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
  resources :password_resets,     only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]

  resources :trainings do
    resources :bookings
  end
  resources :users
end
```

When i go to training show (a specific hour of training) the code is the following:

```
<div class="row">
    <section>
      <h1>
HOUR: <%= @training.hour %>
      </h1>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h1>
SLOTS: <%= @training.slots %>
      </h1>
    </section>
    <center>
    <%= render 'bookings/booking_form' if logged_in? %>
    <%= render 'bookings/index_bookings' if logged_in? %>
  </center>
```

The _index_bookings.html.erb is:

```
<ul class="bookings">
<% if current_user.bookings(@training) %>
  <li>
<%= link_to @training_id, training_bookings_path(@training) %>
</li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

Rake routes:

```
cesar@Dandy:~/Apps/boxApp$ rake routes
                 Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                         Controller#Action
                   root GET    /                                                   static_pages#home
                 signup GET    /signup(.:format)                                   users#new
                contact GET    /contact(.:format)                                  static_pages#contact
                  about GET    /about(.:format)                                    static_pages#about
                  login GET    /login(.:format)                                    sessions#new
                        POST   /login(.:format)                                    sessions#create
                 logout DELETE /logout(.:format)                                   sessions#destroy
                   book GET    /book(.:format)                                     bookings#new
                        POST   /book(.:format)                                     bookings#create
                 unbook DELETE /unbook(.:format)                                   bookings#destroy
edit_account_activation GET    /account_activations/:id/edit(.:format)             account_activations#edit
        password_resets POST   /password_resets(.:format)                          password_resets#create
     new_password_reset GET    /password_resets/new(.:format)                      password_resets#new
    edit_password_reset GET    /password_resets/:id/edit(.:format)                 password_resets#edit
         password_reset PATCH  /password_resets/:id(.:format)                      password_resets#update
                        PUT    /password_resets/:id(.:format)                      password_resets#update
      training_bookings GET    /trainings/:training_id/bookings(.:format)          bookings#index
                        POST   /trainings/:training_id/bookings(.:format)          bookings#create
   new_training_booking GET    /trainings/:training_id/bookings/new(.:format)      bookings#new
  edit_training_booking GET    /trainings/:training_id/bookings/:id/edit(.:format) bookings#edit
       training_booking GET    /trainings/:training_id/bookings/:id(.:format)      bookings#show
                        PATCH  /trainings/:training_id/bookings/:id(.:format)      bookings#update
                        PUT    /trainings/:training_id/bookings/:id(.:format)      bookings#update
                        DELETE /trainings/:training_id/bookings/:id(.:format)      bookings#destroy
              trainings GET    /trainings(.:format)                                trainings#index
                        POST   /trainings(.:format)                                trainings#create
           new_training GET    /trainings/new(.:format)                            trainings#new
          edit_training GET    /trainings/:id/edit(.:format)                       trainings#edit
               training GET    /trainings/:id(.:format)                            trainings#show
                        PATCH  /trainings/:id(.:format)                            trainings#update
                        PUT    /trainings/:id(.:format)                            trainings#update
                        DELETE /trainings/:id(.:format)                            trainings#destroy
                  users GET    /users(.:format)                                    users#index
                        POST   /users(.:format)                                    users#create
               new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                                users#new
              edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                           users#edit
                   user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                                users#show
                        PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                                users#update
                        PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                                users#update
                        DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                                users#destroy
```

Comment: Can you show the output of `rake routes`? I think you can have your bookings#index route use `@bookings = Booking.where(training_id: params[:training_id])`.

Comment: Edited with rake routes

Comment: It worked bro! Add it as a answer so i can accept it! God bless you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write this in your routes:

```
  resources :trainings do
    resources :bookings
  end
```

You can see the result in `rake routes`:

```
  training_bookings GET    /trainings/:training_id/bookings(.:format)
```

This gets routed to `Trainings::BookingsController#index` (you don't have to explicitly declare this mapping; it happens automatically with `resources`).

You can see in the `rake routes` definition the one path parameter (though as always, users could send anything they wanted in the query params after a question mark).  You need to use this `training_id` to filter the bookings returned by the index route; this doesn't  happen automatically just because you nest the route.

This is how you could do that:

```
  def index
    @bookings = Booking.where(training_id: params[:training_id])
  end
```